# Explode, push an element and implode in a single move

Tags: php

My page URL could be one of the belows:

```
/lang/part1/part2/
/part1/part2/
```

I also have a boolean `$hasLocale` that is `TRUE` if `lang` is in the URL, otherwise it's `FALSE` if it's not.

I need to add a string before `part1`, so my URL could become:

```
/lang/somestring/part1/part2/
/somestring/part1/part2/
```

This is my code:

```
if ($hasLocale) {
    $urlArray = explode('/', $url);
    array_splice( $urlArray, 1, 0, ['somestring'] );
    $newUrl = '/' . implode('/', $urlArray);
}
else {
    $newUrl = '/somestring' . $url;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regexp replacement.

```
if ($hasLocale) {
    $newUrl = preg_replace('#^/[^/]*#', '$0/somestring', $url);
} else {
    $newUrl = '/somestring' . $url;
}
```

The regexp matches the initial `/` followed by everything up to, but not including, the next `/`. `$0` in the replacement is replaced with whatever that matched.

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/6KK9hN)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun way.  Get before `part1` concatenate with `somestring` and concatenate with what's after `part1`:

```
$newUrl = strstr($url, 'part1', true) . 'somestring/' . strstr($url, 'part1');
```

Comment: `part1` is not a fixed string, it could be any value